# Postgresql localhost connection - Connection refused

Tags: django, postgresql

i just installed pgadmin iii and try to connect server.

I configured my setting

```
name:localhost
host: 127.0.0.1
port:5432

username:postgres
```

but i always get this error

> The server doesn't accept connection: the connection library reports
>   **could not connect to server : Connection refused Is server runing on host "127.0.0.1" and accepting TCP/IP connections on port 5432?

However, i'm runing django and python on 127.0.0.1 What's missing?

There's also a problem with mysql.  I could not connect with them

Comment: Have you checked if postgresql actually runs?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you change the pg_hba.conf file to accept connections (for example: "host all all 127.0.0.1 255.255.255.0 trust") it should work

Answer (score 0):

Installing postgre v12 before uninstalling v11 I found the config file (postgresql.conf) had a line "port = 5433". Changing this to "port = 5432" fixed the issue for me.