# how to make a database connection using sql alchemy to postgresql and insert dataframe or csv to postgresql database?

Tags: python, postgresql, sqlalchemy, data-science, google-colaboratory

## My main task is to convert or ingest the dataframe to postgressql database

I want to make a connection of the database using sqlalchemy so I want to make a connection with my postgressql database using below code.Kindly help me with this error.
These are the details of my pgadmin:
server name:test
username:postgre
passoword:password
port:5432
host:localhost
In the test server I have 2 databases which are postgre and stores in that I want to ingest the dataframe to the stores database

```
import sqlalchemy               #package to access the sql databases via Python
import psycopg2

#connect to database
engine = sqlalchemy.create_engine("postgresql://postgres:password@localhost/stores")

#verify there are no existing tables
print(engine.table_names())
```

This is the error I am getting after running the above code

```
OperationalError                          Traceback (most recent call last)
/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py in _wrap_pool_connect(self, fn, connection)
   2335         try:
-> 2336             return fn()
   2337         except dialect.dbapi.Error as e:

40 frames
OperationalError: could not connect to server: Connection refused
    Is the server running on host "localhost" (127.0.0.1) and accepting
    TCP/IP connections on port 5432?
could not connect to server: Cannot assign requested address
    Is the server running on host "localhost" (::1) and accepting
    TCP/IP connections on port 5432?


The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

OperationalError                          Traceback (most recent call last)
/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/psycopg2/__init__.py in connect(dsn, connection_factory, cursor_factory, **kwargs)
    128     if cursor_factory is not None:
    129         conn.cursor_factory = cursor_factory
--> 130 
    131     return conn

OperationalError: (psycopg2.OperationalError) could not connect to server: Connection refused
    Is the server running on host "localhost" (127.0.0.1) and accepting
    TCP/IP connections on port 5432?
could not connect to server: Cannot assign requested address
    Is the server running on host "localhost" (::1) and accepting
    TCP/IP connections on port 5432?

(Background on this error at: http://sqlalche.me/e/13/e3q8)
```

Comment: So like the error message says: "Is the server running on host "localhost" (127.0.0.1) and accepting TCP/IP connections on port 5432?"

Comment: how to check it?

Comment: Possibly related: https://stackoverflow.com/q/10823534/2144390

Comment: btw in pgadmin of postgresql,everything is working fine.

Comment: Are the connection parameters in pgAdmin the same as what you are using in the code?

Comment: @AdrianKlaver server name:test, username:postgre,passoword:password,port:5432,host:local host and btw in test server I have 2 databases which  are postgre and stores in that I want to ingest the dataframe to the stores database

Comment: For the SQLAlchemy code are you running it on the same machine as the server and the pgAdmin client? Are there any VM and/or containers involved?  Can you connect using `psql`? Also is the username `postgre` in your pgAdmin connection a misspell?

Comment: I am using google colab in that I have a dataframe from colab I executing this code and pgadmin is installed locally on my laptop and running properly.No there is no vm, and yes I can connect using psql(sql shell),username is  postgres I checked twice.

Comment: Not familiar with Google Colaboratory, though I suspect it is running on Google servers somewhere. In that case trying to connect to `localhost` is not going to work.  You would need to provide the `IP or hostname` for your laptop and allow connections through your firewall.